# Added Row on DatagtridView always on the last row

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

This is my code to add new row on my `datagridview`, Its working fine, but the added row always on the last row of my `datagridview`, I want my added row to be on the next row followed by the row it was originated.

```
DataTable dataTable = (DataTable)dgVSdetail.DataSource;
DataRow drToAdd = dataTable.NewRow();
       drToAdd[0] = rowV.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
       drToAdd[1] = rowV.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
       drToAdd[2] = rowV.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
       drToAdd[3] = rowV.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
       drToAdd[4] = rowV.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
       drToAdd[5] = Convert.ToDecimal(rowV.Cells[5].Value.ToString()) - Convert.ToDecimal(rowV.Cells[6].Value.ToString());
dataTable.Rows.Add(drToAdd);
dataTable.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: can you explain What you mean by "I want my added row to be on the next row followed by the row it was originated"

Comment: Just to clarify I have a dynamic column with button, when i click that button row index the added row should be on the next row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `InsertAt` method of `DataTable.Rows`, then your code will be something like this:

```
int positionToInsertRow= 2;// Get the position that you want
dataTable.Rows.InsertAt(drToAdd, positionToInsertRow);
```

Where `drToAdd` is the row that you want to add to the DataTable, and `positionToInsertRow` is the position/index in which you want to insert the row.

Comment: @odlanyer: Glad to hear that, happy to help you.